# Why is the boolean expression "1 in (1, 2, 3) == True" False?

Tags: python, boolean-logic, operator-precedence

Why does the statement `1 in (1, 2, 3) == True` return `False` in Python?
Is the operator priority in Python ambiguous?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because, per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) on operator precedence:

> Note that comparisons, membership tests, and identity tests, all have
>   the same precedence and have a left-to-right chaining feature as
>   described in the [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) section.

The Comparisons section shows an example of the chaining:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent
>   to `x < y and y <= z`

So:

```
1 in (1, 2, 3) == True
```

is interpreted as:

```
(1 in (1, 2, 3)) and ((1, 2, 3) == True)
```

If you override this chaining by adding parentheses, you get the expected behaviour:

```
>>> (1 in (1, 2, 3)) == True
True
```

Note that, rather than comparing truthiness by equality to `True` or `False`, you should just use e.g. `if thing:` and `if not thing:`.

Comment: Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z

Comment: @宏杰李 yes that is true - I've literally just added that quote from the docs!

Comment: we got same idea, lol

Comment: Also, if you explicitly want to compare to `True` use `stuff is True`, not `stuff == True`