# "In" Check not working in if Statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I was doing some basic string manipulation and I came across something very interesting and confusing:

```
str= "HELLO WORLD"
x="LL"

t = x in str
print t

if x in str == True:
    print "TRUE"
```

When it's run, it currently only prints True on one occasion, on the first print statement. One would think that both would print as logically and almost syntactically they are the same yet one does not. I do not understand the reasoning behind this, especially given how Python is supposed to be intuitive.

Comment: FWIW, the `== True` is entirely redundant and can/should be omitted.

Comment: use without `== True` - `if x in str:` - now it is treated as `if x in (str == True):`

Comment: @furas: No, if it were parsed that way, there'd be a `TypeError`. The `in` and `==` actually apply comparison chaining, like in `1 < x < 5`.

Comment: and `str` is a built-in; you should never overwrite any of those or you will encounter unpleasant surprises...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/41075735/3001761

Comment: Operator chaining should really be limited to ==, <=, !=, >= in my opinion, this sort of thing is *always* surprising. But too late for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protect your condition into parentheses:

```
if (x in str) == True:
    print("TRUE")
```

Even better: it's redundant to compare to `True`

```
if x in str:
    print("TRUE")
```

That said, it's *not* beacuse of operator precedence:

```
x in (str == True)
```

is invalid (cannot iterate on a boolean)

```
x in str == True
```

is valid but returns `False`. I must admit I'm still puzzled about that...

EDIT: just saw the duplicate and now I get it. Lesson #1: always protect your expressions with parentheses when you have a doubt.